# Regular expression to match any character repeated exactly twice

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to identify whether a supplied string has characters repeated exactly twice. The following is the regular expression that I am using:

```
([a-z])\1(?!\1)
```

However, when tested against the following strings, both the strings below are matching the pattern (though I have used (?!\1):

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*([a-z])\1(?!\1)', 'abcdeefg')
['e']
>>> re.findall(r'.*([a-z])\1(?!\1)', 'abcdeeefg')
['e']
```

What is wrong in the above pattern?

Comment: If it helps you think about it ... in the latter example the pattern is matching the `eef` portion of the string

Comment: What's the expected output if the input is `acedeefg`?

Comment: Thanks @donkopotamus. I agree, it is matching the eef portion. I would like it to match only abcdeefg and not abcdeeefg

Comment: Then add a negative lookbehind as well.

Comment: @KennethK. could you make it as an answer?

Comment: @KennethK. how?  You can't use a back reference in a negative lookbehind, and even if you could, at the point you'd need it, the capture hasn't yet happened, so `\1` wouldn't yet be set.

Comment: @PaulL Yeah, I just found that out. I guess I'm spoiled by C#  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that a python regular expression alone will not meet your needs.  In order to ensure that a character is repeated exactly twice will require a negative look behind assertion, and such assertions cannot contain group references.

The easiest approach is to instead look for all repetitions and simply check their length.

```
def double_repeats(txt):
    import itertools

    # find possible repeats
    candidates = set(re.findall(r'([a-z])\1', txt))

    # now find the actual repeated blocks
    repeats = itertools.chain(*[re.findall(r"({0}{0}+)".format(c), txt) for c in candidates])

    # return just the blocks of length 2
    return [x for x in repeats if len(x) == 2]
```

Then:

```
>>> double_repeats("abbbcbbdddeffgggg")
['ff', 'bb']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex alternate operator trick.

```
>>> def guess(s):
    out = re.findall(r'([a-z])\1{2,}|([a-z])\2', s)
    if out and out[0][1]:
        return True
    return False

>>> k = ['abcdeefg', 'abcdeeefg']
>>> [guess(i) for i in k]
[True, False]
>>>
```

- `([a-z])\1{2,}` matches all the repeated characters having a minimum of 3 maximum of n characters.
- `|` OR
- `([a-z])\2` matches exactly two repeated characters from the remaining string since all the same continuous characters are matched by the first pattern.

or

```
>>> def guess(s):
    out = re.findall(r'([a-z])\1{2,}|([a-z])\2', s)
    if out and out[0][1]:
        return out[0][1]
    return False
>>> k =  '23413e4abcee'
>>> k.count(guess(k)) == 2
False
>>> k =  '234134abcee'
>>> k.count(guess(k)) == 2
True
>>>
```

If you want to get output like the other answers, then here you go:

```
>>> def guess(s):
    out = re.findall(r'([a-z])\1{2,}|([a-z])\2', s)
    if out:
        return [y+y for x,y in out if y]
    return []

>>> guess("abbbcbbdddeffgggg")
['bb', 'ff']
>>>
```

Comment: This is nice.  One wrinkle is that `guess('aaabaa')` will currently return `False` despite `a` being repeated exactly twice.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. Both answers are working

Answer (score -3):

I find it the best way to do that.

[image: I find it the best way to do that:]

Comment: The solution seems to check if the supplied string has at least 2 letters "a" (or "A").  It does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @aaabbb sir I was not doing his homework, I was trying to show him the way. I hope you know how to convert "a" into "[a-z]"

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64281631/edit) the right thing  (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.